# Format a list of strings from a csv file

Tags: javascript

```
    <template>
        <form enctype="multipart/form-data">
                <input type="file" @change="onFileChange">
        </form>

    </template>

    <script>

data() {
    return {
       fileinput: ''
   }
}
    methods: {
    onFileChange: function(e) {
          var files = e.target.files || e.dataTransfer.files;
          if (!files.length) return;
          this.createInput(files[0]);
        },

        createInput(file) {
          var reader = new FileReader();
          var vm = this;
          reader.onload = e => {
            vm.fileinput = reader.result;

          };
          reader.readAsText(file);
        },

 watch: {
    fileinput: {
      handler: function(val) {
        let csv_result = val;
        let split = csv_result.split(',');
        let name = split[0];
        let email = split[1];
        console.log(name);
        console.log(email);

      }
    }
  }
    }
    </script>
```

I have a function which takes a csv file in.
The csv file has two columns, name and email;
The function then returns the result which is a list of names and emails as:

```
Name,Email
fooname foosurname,fooemail@gmail.com
fooname1 foosurname1,fooemail1@gmail.com
fooname2 foosurname2,fooemail2@gmail.com
```

The log on the watch return:

```
Name
Email
fooname foosurname
```

What I am trying to achieve is to have an array of object which will have full name and email for each row.

```
[
  { name: "fooname foosurname", email: "fooemail@gmail.com" },
  ...
]
```

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Well what did you try?

Comment: Sorry I hit "submit" despite the post not being fully updated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try

```
csv.split(/\r?\n/).map(x=>x.split(/,/)).map(x=>({name:x[0],email:x[1]}) )
```

```js
let csv=`Name,Email
fooname foosurname,fooemail@gmail.com
fooname1 foosurname1,fooemail1@gmail.com
fooname2 foosurname2,fooemail2@gmail.com`

let r= csv.split(/\r?\n/).map(x=>x.split(/,/)).map(x=>({name:x[0],email:x[1]}) );

r.shift(); // remove header (first item)
console.log(r);
```

Comment: Like a charm! Thank you very much!